# Plotting two lists

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have the following lists:

```
l1={97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97,
97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97,
97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97,
97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97,
97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97,
97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97};

l2={{52.4362, 97}}
```

I would plot together them as:

```
Show[l1 // ListLinePlot,
 l2 // ListPlot]
```

Note I used list line plot and list plot in format as appropriate to my general example which I would want to use this. The resulting plot is:

[image]

However, I want to cut the rest of `x` after 52.4362. So I want to plot this up until 52.4362. How is this possible? Note that I have simplified my example in real problem I have many lists so I can not simply cut `l1` to desired length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** A generalization to pairs of multiple lists:

```
trim = MapThread[#[[;;Floor[#2[[1]]]]] &, {If[Length@Dimensions@# == 1, {#}, #], #2}]&;
```

**Examples:**

```
Show[trim[l1, l2] // ListLinePlot, l2 // ListPlot]
```

[image]

```
l1 = {Table[95, {i, 97}], Table[96, {i, 97}], Table[97, {i, 97}]}; 
l2 = {{44.0866, 95}, {45.628, 96}, {52.4362, 97}};
Show[trim[l1, l2] // ListLinePlot, l2 // ListPlot]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
Show[l1[[;; Floor[l2[[1, 1]]]]] // ListLinePlot, l2 // ListPlot]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
l1b = Select[#[[1]] <= l2[[1, 1]] &]@MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, l1];
ListPlot[{l2, l1b}, Joined -> {False, True}]
```

[image]

Or use the option `PlotRange`:

```
Show[l1 // ListLinePlot, l2 // ListPlot, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, l2[[1, 1]]}, All}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.005]]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[{l2, l1}, Joined -> {False, True}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, l2[[1, 1]]}, All}, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.0025]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @kglr as always. I am trying to generalise this what if I have: `l1={Table[95, {i, 97}], Table[96, {i, 97}], Table[97, {i, 97}]}` and `l2={{44.0866, 95}, {45.628, 96}, {52.4362, 97}}` how can I generalise this method?

Comment: @William, does `Show[l1[[All, ;; Floor[l2[[-1, 1]]]]] // ListLinePlot, l2 // ListPlot]` give the desired result? or do you need to cut `Table[95, {i, 97}]` at `44.0866` and `Table[96, {i, 97}]` at `45.628` etc?

Comment: the latter is needed indeed, i.e Table[95, {i, 97}] cut at 44.0866,  Table[95, {i, 97}] cut at 45.628 and so on.

Comment: @William, please see the update.

Answer (score 2):

```
Plot[Interpolation[l1][x], {x, 0, l2[[1, 1]]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, Length[l1]}, Automatic}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point /@ l2}] // Quiet
```

[image]